# Unable to find the element using XPath

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

**XPath:** `//*[@id=\"clB\"]/div[1]/div[1]/a/div`

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@id=\"clB\"]/div[1]/div[1]/a/div because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@id=\"clB\"]/div[1]/div[1]/a/div' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:19.891Z'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-9TR048UG', ip: '192.168.2.4', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '9.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6..., userDataDir: C:\Users\eruma\AppData\Loca...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 67.0.3396.99, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 7baaf6e885b283703ef05c4e5ffe3ff2
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[@id=\"clB\"]/div[1]/div[1]/a/div}
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:322)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:424)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:314)
    at automationTester.Blogs1.main(Blogs1.java:25)
```

Comment: Just posting a stacktrace is not the way to ask a question. Fix your styling and add a proper question, describing the current situation.

Comment: put the html you are trying to attach to in the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

`InvalidSelectorException` is thrown by `WebDriver.findElement(By by)` when the selector which is used to find an element is invalid. It can be a query with syntax errors, e.g. `XPath` or `CSS` query with syntax errors, or a compound class name passed as an argument to `By.className()`, or the expression does not select `WebElements` (e.g. "`count(//input)`").

Now you can check what is the mistake you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below xpath:

```
//[@id='clB']/div[1]/div[1]/a/div
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below syntax by using contains.

Most of the automation testing company avoid the **XPath**.

```
  //[contains(@id,'clB')]//div[1]//div[1]//a//div
```

Please revert back if it fails. Also, provide the complete error.